# IIS php-cgi process remain open after ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, iis

I've got the following scenario: multiple users from local network access a web application in coded in php resident on a IIS server. At every page load 3 ajax calls to 3 separated php script are performed and these calls repeat themselves every X minutes (timed jquery). For every ajax call of every user connected a php-cgi session is opened on the server, adding quickly up to 20 or so processes. The problem is after the ajax call these processes remain open, thus using a large amount of memory on the server with consequential problems to performances (arriving at a total block at times).
All the php scripts are called via the jQuery $.post function and perform one or more queries on a mssql db and end echoing a json encoded object or array. Is there a way to make these process close after the execution of the php script? I would like to avoid the option of making serial calls instead of parallel ones.
Any help is strongly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you have already got a solution but anyways:

Try adding a

```
die();
?>
```

at the end of the php scripts that are called. That would kill the scripts that are called after they have completed execution. As each call creates its own process, their would be no issues even if things are done in parallel.